# Embedding LookerStudio Report and Implementing Dynamic Filtering

Tags: javascript, iframe, looker-studio

I'm currently working on embedding a LookerStudio report within my webpage using an iframe and the provided embed report link, which follows this format: https://lookerstudio.google.com/embed/reporting/REPORT_ID/page/PAGE_ID.

At the moment, the embedded report displays all the data within the iframe. However, I need to implement a feature that dynamically filters the data based on the organization of the logged-in user in my web application.

Could someone provide guidance or suggest a solution for achieving this dynamic filtering functionality? Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

[This is how my report looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXIzp.png)

I've already been through these articles and videos:

1. https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/connector/embed-row-level-security
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi0_Je-ILNk

Answer (score 0):

by using parameters and configuring your data source to filter based on parameter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).